# Github Actions and npm - npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, github-actions, nvm

I've created a action for a deployment on github actions. This all works with composer install and git pulling the master branch. However on my digital ocean droplet, I get the issue
`bash: line 4: npm: command not found`
If i ssh into my server i can use npm perfectly fine. This was installed via nvm and uses the latest version but for some reason its not accessable via the action.
My deployment script is

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy Laravel APP
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.4
        with:
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} 
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}} 
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }} 

          script: |
            cd /var/www/admin
            git pull origin master
            composer install
            npm install
            npm run prod
```

I presume this is more to do with the setup from nvm as i can use this via ssh but as  they use the same user to log in via ssh, i can't seem to see an issue.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue to give access/allow github actions to use npm?

Comment: You need to setup node in the runner with the [setup/node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) first. In a step before using the appleboy/ssh-action.

Comment: I don't beleive this is the issue, I've just tried that but still dont have access to npm. Would that not enable npm on the action but not the server? I think the issue is with the npm installation on the server.

Comment: It might be because you also need to use the `action/checkout` as well to access the **package.json** file with the `npm install` command

Comment: Turns out it was the npm install on the server.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and finally found the solution.
I could solve the issue by adding the following lines before running `npm` commands.

```bash
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

These commands *helps the terminal fix the node path* installed by `nvm`.
Reference link is [here](https://gist.github.com/danielwetan/4f4db933531db5dd1af2e69ec8d54d8a?permalink_comment_id=4057972#gistcomment-4057972).

Comment: Can confirm this worked on our github action!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution for the nvm issue, installing npm via a different way resoleved this issue.

Comment: and what was the different way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @iconique is correct. I just had to tweak it a bit to point to the correct location of `.nvm.sh`

To see the exact location of your `.nvm.sh`, you need to run

```
whereis pm2
```

In my case, I updated the `.yml` file as follows:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build & Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Production
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          script: |
            export NVM_DIR=/home/${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}/.nvm
            source /home/${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}/.nvm/nvm.sh
            git stash
            git pull origin main
            npm i
            npm run build
```